# How to do group by in the generated table

Tags: database, oracle

I have two tables Salespeople and members where salesid is pk in salespeople table and foreignkey in members table and I am trying to get the count of number of members each salesperson is working with.

But my sql query is throwing an error stating not a group by expression. I tried solving it using the joins but that didn't work either.

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, COUNT(s.salesid) AS MemCount
FROM salespeople s
  LEFT JOIN members m ON s.salesid = m.salesid
  GROUP BY s.salesid;
```

`ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

I would appreciate if any one can throw some light on this issue.

Many Thanks.
[image]

Comment: `s.salesid` is not  a part of the selection and if its primary key just add that in the select list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting fields `(firstname, lastname)` not in your `group by` `(salesid)`. Because fields that are not in your `group by` could vary within a group, the db won't know which value from the group to return, so a lot of dbs won't let you select fields that are not in your group by.

You can modify your query by adding firstname, lastname to your group by i.e.

`... group by m.salesid, s.firstname, s.lastname`

Comment: Thanks...it worked                                                                                                                                                                                                               select s.firstname,s.lastname,count(s.firstname) as MemCount from salespeople s, members m where s.salesid = m.salesid group by s.firstname,s.lastname;